# Trying to execute command from Nodejs (exec) throw error but works in terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, child-process, regedit

I'm trying to run this script

```js
let { exec } = require("child_process");

let command =
  "reg add 'HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\MySoftware' /v 'LOADER' /t REG_SZ /d 'C:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\some.dll' /f";

exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

and always get the error `ERROR: Invalid key name`. I was thinking that maybe the `reg` command was incorrect but if I run it in the terminal it works.

I'm not sure what can be incorrect, I really appreciate it if you give me some feedback. Thanks

Comment: Don't use single quotes `'`  for enclosing string values but double quotes `"` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace `'` with `"` for values

```
let { exec } = require("child_process");

let command =
  'reg add "HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\MySoftware" /v "LOADER" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\some.dll" /f';

exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```